# hi from my db i am getting a value as string type and when i am displaying in in my jsf page it is displaying as 12.0

Tags: jsf

hi from my db i am getting a value as string type and when i am displaying in in my jsf page it is displaying as 12.0 but i want to display it as 12.00

can i do that by changing the data type from string to double 
or any other ways
can any one please suggest me?

thanks 
Suresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<f:convertNumber/>` [component](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/convertNumber.html) for that.

Here is how it works to have 2 digits for the fraction part of your number:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myValue}">
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2"/>
</h:outputText>
```